# Running XMBC 12 off a stick, sans HDD

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb-flash-drive, livecd, kodi

I have a laptop whose hard drive is toast, so I'm booting XBMC off a stick.  It works fine, but I would like to not have to manually intervene halfway through booting up to tell it to Try Ubuntu, since I can't install it on anything.  How do I get it to just boot straight into XBMC off the stick?

Also, I seem to have to adjust the volume amplification up every time I boot, despite telling it to save the settings at the bottom of the audio panel.  Any network shares are also forgotten, and the time zone is reset.  How do I get it to save these things back to the stick so I don't need to keep re-doing them?